# Using the "add" method to add object to ArrayList but it's not adding properly

Tags: java, intellij-idea, arraylist

As the title says, I was trying to add a class object instance to an ArrayList but apparently it isn't adding anything.

I'm trying to add an object to an ArrayList using the following syntax:

```
    public void adicionarMedicaoAux(Medicao m){this.medicoes.add(m); }
```

This is the "toString()":

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Ficha de Utente\n------------------\n" +
                "Utente: " + utente + " | " +
                "Familiar(res) do utente: " + familiarUtente + " | " +
                "Medições: " + medicoes + " | " +
                "Prescrições: " + prescricoes + " | " +
                "Exames: " + exames + " | " +
                "Consultas: " + consultas;
    }
```

This method is then used here:

```
public void AdicionarMedicao(String num_utente, LocalDate data, double peso, double altura, int tensao_arterial, int saturacao_oxigenio, int imc) throws RemoteException, UtenteNaoExiste {
        c1+=1;
        Medicao m = new Medicao(data, peso, altura, tensao_arterial, saturacao_oxigenio, imc);
        medicoes.put(String.valueOf(c1),m);
        FichaUtente fichautente = new FichaUtente(getUtenteEspecifico(num_utente));
        fichautente.adicionarMedicaoAux(m);
    }
```

Finally it gets called in the client:

```
System.out.println("Introduza o ID de utente seguido das medições efetuadas (ID utente, peso,altura,tensão arterial, saturação de oxigénio): ");
                            String medicaonova = scanner.nextLine();
                            String[] medicaopartes = medicaonova.split(",", -1);
                            LocalDate data = LocalDate.now();
                            Double peso = Double.parseDouble(medicaopartes[1]);
                            Double altura = Double.parseDouble(medicaopartes[2]);
                            Integer tens_art = Integer.parseInt(medicaopartes[3]);
                            Integer sat_ox = Integer.parseInt(medicaopartes[4]);
                            Double imc_d = peso / (altura*altura);
                            Integer imc = imc_d.intValue();
                            mi.AdicionarMedicao(medicaopartes[0],data,peso,altura,tens_art,sat_ox,imc);
```

This is the final output:

```
001 - Ficha de Utente
------------------
Utente: Utente: Nome: Luís | Nif: 241637341 | CC: 14422517 | Data de nascimento: 2002-06-18 | Número do utente: 001 | Telefone: 910410666 | Telefone familiar: 914504925 | E-mail: luiscunhadrawings@gmail.com | Morada: Rua do Nascente n38 Gualtar Braga | Familiar(res) do utente: [] | Medições: [] | Prescrições: [] | Exames: [] | Consultas: []
```

As you can see the "Medições" part shows a blank ArrayList instead of what was added.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

```
FichaUtente fichautente = new FichaUtente(getUtenteEspecifico(num_utente));
        fichautente.adicionarMedicaoAux(m);
```

This code:

- Makes a new object of type FiuchaUtente and assigns to local variable `fichautente`
- Calls a method on that.
- **Then tosses it all straight into the garbage**.

Only that local var refers the newly created object, and local vars go into the garbage when a method ends.